# How to test an http request in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have a service like this.

It is simply just make a http get request.

```
angular.module('myApp').service('TESTService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var request = function(url) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url
            });
        };
        return {
            get: function(url) {
                return request(url);
            }            
        };
    }
]);
```

Within my controller, I have called the service

```
 TESTService.get('/api/product' + id).success(
            function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            }
        );
```

I need to write the unit test for it

```
describe('test here', function () {
var testCtrl, scope, httpBackend, testService;

// Initialize the controller and a mock scope
beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$httpBackend_,  _TESTService_) {
    scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    testService = _TESTService_;

    testCtrl = _$controller_('testCtrl', {
        $scope: scope
    });



     it('should return http data', function() {
        var productData = {
           data: [
                {
                  obj: {
                    id:'123'
                  }
                }           
            ]
        }

        httpBackend.expectGET('/api/product/' + id).respond(productData);

        TESTService.get('/api/product/' + id).
            then(function(data) {
                var result = data;
            })

        httpBackend.flush();
        expect(result).toEqual(productData)
    });
 }));
```

After running the test, I got

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/product/undefined
```

How do I write the test to make sure it passes? Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just as a side note, testing a service that is using `$http` is an integration test, not a unit test.  Unit Tests are able to be performed in isolation, without the presence of servers, databases, etc.  Normally you don't need to do these kind of integration tests anyway, as `$http` is already known functional from Angular and your backend service should be tested on the server.  In other tests, this service would be mocked.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "id" seems to be undefined. If you throw in

```
var id = 123;
```

before this line:

```
httpBackend.expectGET('/api/product/' + id).respond(productData);
```

It would call /api/product/123 instead.

So maybe you were looking for this in the first place:

```
 httpBackend.expectGET('/api/product/' + productData.data[0].obj.id).respond(productData);

 TESTService.get('/api/product/' + productData.data[0].obj.id).
```

And so on... Hope it helps!

Comment: I did what you suggested. It still says Unexpected request: GET /api/product/undefined   expect GET /api/product/12345 +1 though

Answer (score 0):

Try putting single quotes around the object that's passed into $http, i.e. $http({method: 'GET', **'url'**, url});

```
angular.module('myApp').service('TESTService', ['$http',
    function($http) {
        var request = function(url) {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                'url': url
            });
        };
        return {
            get: function(url) {
                return request(url);
            }            
        };
    }
]);
```